# laravelx8 QueryException error while save model (ex:Reservation) need Apostrophes insert value items

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I am using laravelx8 having problem with models query insert

```
use App\Models\Reservation;

from Reservation Models

     $reservation = new Reservation();
     $reservation->name = $username;
     $reservation->email = $email;
     $reservation->phone = $Phone;
     $reservation->read = 0;
     $reservation->payed = 0;
     $reservation->tableId = $tableId;
     $reservation->save();
```

Error is:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY' (SQL: insert into `resorvations` (`name`, `email`, `phone`, `read`, `payed`, `tableId`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (bikash dash, bikash@omsysinfo.in, 9937090484, 0, 0, 7, 2020-12-29 11:14:46, 2020-12-29 11:14:46))

the found that
the QueryException if laravel support only mysql 8 but in my case the mysql5.5(mariaDB) need Apostrophes so it will insert into database eassly by laravel Query Builder

SQL: insert into `resorvations` (`name`, `email`, `phone`, `read`, `payed`, `tableId`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values ('bikash dash', 'bikash@omsysinfo.in', '9937090484', 0, 0, 7, '2020-12-29 11:14:46', '2020-12-29 11:14:46')

Comment: have you read this `1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY' (`

Comment: the problem is mysql 8 and mysql 5.5 , while inserting values items should be inside ('') Apostrophes but laravel*8 dose not support that

Comment: truncate `resorvations` this table and try to insert

Comment: no brother its working on my local system, but on server it cusses problem

Comment: ohh then update in your server mysql

Comment: Strange problem. Can you post your `resorvations` migration file?

Comment: As Kamlesh Paul reported, the error you are reporting has nothing to do with apostrophes (Laravel is doing parameterised queries, not a straight SQL string, so you'll often see the raw SQL without apostrophes). You are getting the error due to the invalid structure of your table.

Comment: yes i found it its a database table error,